# Include many jars in clojure resource-paths

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen

Till now I add some jars under lib/ folder and then I write "lib/a.jar" in "resources-path" field inside project.clj. Now I want to add 20 jars. Is there a better and shorter to way to declare these jars instead of explicitly define each jar one-by-one?

Comment: What are these JARs? Libraries? If so, why are you manually adding them to your resource path instead of letting Leiningen manage your dependencies for you?

Comment: Yes. These are libraries I would like to import.

Comment: Which libraries? Are they not available from [Clojars](https://clojars.org/) or [Central](https://search.maven.org/)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! These are jars from Google libraries, such as "com.google.api. .... . jar"

Comment: I found [these libraries](https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|com.google.api) in Central; do you need any that can't be found there?

Comment: So as a workaround we could say that we could add them (if found) as dependencies instead of downloading them and declaring them into resource-paths. I didn't know that this is also feasible in Clojure! Nice! You could post an answer in order to give you my credits if you wish!! I suppose that in case of custom jars we should always declare them explicitly inside resource-paths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Leiningen projects, the standard way to handle [dependencies](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#dependencies) is to add them to your `:dependencies` vector in `project.clj`. For instance, if your only dependencies are [GAX-Java](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java) and Clojure itself, your dependencies vector would look like this:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
               [com.google.api/gax "0.0.13"]]
```

By default, Leiningen will look for dependencies in the [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/) and [Clojars](https://clojars.org/) repositories, so in this case, it will find [this artifact](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.clojure%7Cclojure%7C1.8.0%7Cjar) for Clojure and [this artifact](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.api%7Cgax%7C0.0.13%7Cjar) for GAX-Java.

If you need a library that's available in a different repository, but is not available in Central or Clojars, you can add that repository as explained [in the Leiningen tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#repositories).

Finally, if you need a library that can't be found in *any* Maven repository, you can download the JAR manually and put it in a directory in your `:resource-paths`, but that isn't generally recommended and should only be used as a last resort.